# DataBase is locked in Django project

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm developing a chatbot chatting page that uses a DB.sqlit3 as a knowledge base for reply to users questions .Also, a have a admin chatting page for the admin to add new question and reply to DB.sqlit3 by chatting.So, for that i have 2 python script (one for the chatbot chatting and one for the admin chatting) each with its own html and JS.

The chatbot chatting page works fine but sometime when i run the admin chatting page after and try to insert new data ( questions and replay) to DB.sqlit3 i get :

```
The database is locked
```

Thank you,

PS:
i'm using Django 10 , python3 , sqlite3, web faction server

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite is not for production. It uses a single global database level lock. Only one thread or process can access it at a time. This is not what you want in production, and definitely not for a chat server. Look into a key value store like Redis for the chat and use a better DB for everything else.

Comment: thank you, some says that switching to mysql will solve the problem because it has a better concurrency. Also, what you mean is that for the conversation i can use Redis and for updating the chatbot database i can use another DB

Comment: A database is not a good tool for doing chat. Something like a fast key value store like Reddis would be better. But if you're just starting out and are trying to learn something you can do it with the db.